# Can I access the BlackBerry Javascript API from a webpage?

Tags: api, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

Would it be possible to, after gaining the user's permission, access the javascript API on BlackBerry devices from a mobile webapp? Sort of in the same way you can request permission  from a user to access their Facebook information?

I know it's possible to create a native app in HTML5+JavaScript using WebWorks and gain access to it there, but for the solution we're building asking the user to download an app would be over-kill.

Answer (score 1):

No, the stock BlackBerry browser won't allow you to access any WebWorks extensions. Javascript extensions need to be explicitly loaded by a native (Java) application into the `BrowserField`.

This is probably a security feature.